# Command that spits out exact display mode used? (Including DSC, chroma subsampling, etc.)

Tags: display, display-settings, displayport

Are there any commands out there that will tell me something like:

```
Current display mode: 3840x2160, 120Hz, 10-bit, YCbCr422 (DSC unsupported)
Available display modes:
* 3840x2160, 120Hz, 8-bit, RGB444
* 3840x2160, 120Hz, 8-bit, YCbCr444
* 3840x2160, 60Hz, 10-bit, RGB444
* etc.
```

Everything I've seen so far is missing information on bitrate, chroma subsampling, and DSC status.

Comment: Everything : Do you include **xrandr** ? https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.5/doc/man/man1/xrandr.1.html

Comment: xrandr is the first thing I tried, and it does not seem to include chroma subsampling or DSC information.